# React how to nest .map function

Tags: reactjs

i am working on a basic react app, where i use the Pokeapi to fetch some data. This data will be stored within the state.

My intention is to render each generation as a bootstrap col-md-x, should i use a single function for each generation or one function that renders all generations at once?

Snippet of component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';
import Loader from './Loader';
import * as PokeService from '../services/PokeService'

export default class PokeOverview extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            generations: {
                firstGen: [],
                secondGen: [],
                thirdGen: [],
                fourthGen: [],
                fifthGen: [],
                sixthGen: [],
                seventhGen: [],
            }
        };
        this.isLoading = true;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.isLoading = false;
        PokeService.getFirstGen().then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                generations: {
                    ...this.state.generations,
                    firstGen: response.results
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error.message))

        PokeService.getSecondGen().then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                generations: {
                    ...this.state.generations,
                    secondGen: response.results
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
        console.log(this.state.generations);
    }
    renderFirstGen() {
        console.log(this.state.generations);
        return this.state.generations.firstGen.map((gen, i) => {
            return <Pokemon key={i} name={gen.name} />
        });
    }
    renderAllGens() {
        Object.keys(this.state.generations).map((generation) => {
            return this.state.generations[generation].map((pokemon, i ) => (
                <Pokemon key={i} name={pokemon.name} />
            ))
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <section>
                <h3>Pokemon list:</h3>
                <ol className="pokemon-list">
                    {!this.isLoading ? this.renderAllGens() : (<Loader/>)}
                </ol>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Snippet of service:

```js
export const getFirstGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=0", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getSecondGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=100&offset=152", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getThirdGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=135&offset=252", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getFourthGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=107&offset=387", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getFifthGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=156&offset=494", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getSixthGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=72&offset=650", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
export const getSeventhGen = () => {
    return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=300&offset=722", {
        cache: "force-cache"
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
```

[Printscreen of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkkDg.png)

Comment: add return to the map statement

Comment: So the setState has to be `firstGen: response.results`??

Comment: You're right, I shall mark your answer as correct. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.pokemon` is an object which is not mappable. You can use the function `Object.keys()` which retrieves all keys in the object as an array and map over it.

```
return Object.keys(this.state.generations).map((generation) => {
     return this.state.generations[generation].map((gen, i ) => (
        <Pokemon key={i} name={gen.name} />
     ))
 });
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      generations: {
        firstGen: ['one', 'two'],
        secondGen: ['three', 'four']
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          Object.keys(this.state.generations).map(gen=>{
            return this.state.generations[gen].map(name=>(
              <p>{name}</p>
            ));
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Also, `this.setState` needs only the updated state variables, you do not need to spread the entire state. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

```
this.setState((prevState)=>{
  generations: {
    ...prevState.generations,
    firstGen: response
  }
});
```

Comment: Upon using this code, i receive the error: **TypeError: _this3.state.pokemons[generation].map is not a function**. Also don't i have to keep all the previous states if i a want to add more asynchronous data to the state?

Comment: @Regentix Sorry. Typo. It is `this.state.generations` I have updated the answer

Comment: I'm still getting the error: **TypeError: _this3.state.pokemons[generation].map is not a function**

Comment: @Regentix It is `this.state.generations` like I mentioned. See updated answer

Comment: I am using the code that you provided. Would it be better in my case to make a single function for every generation?

Comment: @Regentix I think you are still using `this.state.pokemon` If you are using that anywhere change them to `this.state.generations`

Comment: I updated my question and provided "currently using"

Comment: **_this4.state.generations[generation].map is not a function** check question for printscreen

Comment: @Regentix I have added a working snippet as to how it should work

Comment: I am still getting that same error.. It might be because i forgot to add that the response has the pokemon names in an the array: results. I will update question

Comment: I also added a snippet with the full component code

Comment: Most of the interesting part I need to know is in the services and what it returns.

Comment: I added a snippet of the services and the fetch response